# Suggest semantic tags for short snippets of text

Tags: python, tags, semantics, named-entity-recognition

I am interested in generating a list of suggested semantic tags (via links to Freebase, Wikipedia or another system) to a user who is posting a short text snippet.  I'm not looking to "understand" what the text is *really* saying, or even to automatically tag it, I just want to suggest to the user the most likely semantic tags for his/her post.  My main goal is to force users to tag semantically and therefore consistently and not to write in ambiguous text strings.  If there were a reasonably functional and reasonably priced tool on the market, I would use it.  I have not found such a tool so I am looking in to writing my own.

My question is first of all, if there is such a tool that I have not encountered.  I've looked at Zemanta, AlchemyAPI and OpenCalais and none of them seemed to offer the service I need.

Assuming that I'm writing my own, I'd be doing it in Python (unless there was a really compelling reason to use something else).  My first guess would be to search for n-grams that match "entities" in Freebase and suggest them as tags, perhaps searching in descriptions of entities as well to get a little "smarter."  If that proved insufficient, I'd read up and dip my toes into the ontological water.  Since this is a *very* hard problem and I don't think that my application requires its solution, I would like to refrain from real semantic analysis as much as possible.

Does anyone have experience working with a semantic database system and could give me some pointers regarding where to begin and what sort of pitfalls to expect?

Comment: Named entity extraction is a bit more complex than searching ngrams, but it could be a reasonable approach. Do you expect the snippets to fall in the same domain or is your problem completely open ended?

Comment: I require a "category" tag from a drop down list of ~25 but beyond that, it's open ended.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at NLTK python library.  It contains a vast number of tools, dictionaries and algorithms.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it.  If anyone has some more specific experience with named entity recognition, I would appreciate it.